# iterate through an object from specific point

Tags: javascript

I want to iterate through the `Cards` object from specific point (`const start`) and find the first matching value of `target` then just break the loop and log a simple console log:

```js
const Cards = {

    1: {
  val: "this is the value 1"
  },
  
  2: {
  val: "this is the value 2"
  },
  
  3: {
  val: "this is the value 3"
  },
  
  4: {
  val: "target"
  },
  
  5: {
  val: "this is the value 5"
  },
  
  6: {
  val: "this is the value 6"
  },
  
  7: {
  val: "target"
  },
  
}


const start = 2; // start searching the target from here

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(Cards)) {
  // we start from 2 and in 4 we reach the first target so in 4 we should break the loop
  
     console.log(value.val)

}
```

**Note:** the keys in object are always 1,2,3,4...n

Comment: You are going to start from the key value = `2` for example?

Comment: What's your desired output? Please include more details.

Comment: yes I want to start from the key` value = 2`

Comment: I want to change the `val` of  first matching iteration...

Comment: You really should use an array instead of an object here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a number of ways, this is how I would do it:

```js
const Cards = {
  1: { val: "this is the value 1" },
  2: { val: "this is the value 2" },
  3: { val: "this is the value 3" },
  4: { val: "target" },
  5: { val: "this is the value 5" },
  6: { val: "this is the value 6" },
  7: { val: "target" },
};

// start searching the target from here
const start = 2;
const entries = Object.entries(Cards);

// we start from 2 and in 4 we reach the first target so in 4 we should break the loop
for (let i = start; i < entries.length; i++) {
  const [key, value] = entries[i];
  console.log(value.val);
}
```

Comment: You mention finding the match and breaking the loop, but your code doesn't show it. 
`if (value == 'target') {updateVal(); break;}`

Comment: @user1599011 I focused on the question posed in the title "iterate through an object from specific point", I assume OP knowns about if-statements.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
const Cards = {
  1: { val: "this is the value 1" },
  2: { val: "this is the value 2" },
  3: { val: "this is the value 3" },
  4: { val: "target" },
  5: { val: "this is the value 5" },
  6: { val: "this is the value 6" },
  7: { val: "target" },
};

const start = 2 


for(i = 2; i <= Object.keys(Cards).length; i++){
     if(Cards[i].val === 'target'){
        console.log(`value found at ${i}`)
        return
     }
}
```

Comment: @Uni- Looks like I made an error. It should be i <= Object.keys(Cards).length